# 3D visualization of geological data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d, visualisation, geology

I'm checking the possiblities of 3D visualization in QGIS for geological data. At the moment I am trying to visualize the surface raster and the sub-surface rasters together in a 3D View.

It should look like this:

[image]

I checked the 3D Map View, but I can only define the DTM was height reference. When I'm doing this, the other rasters are also refered to that height...
In the Qgis2threejs Plugin, the sub-surface is not visible, because it extrudes the DTM to a block.

Does anybody know some settings to configure the 3D Map View?

Comment: What comes to my mind is to visualize these layers in Blender. There is an addon for Blender that allows you to import GIS raster layers (https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS). Then you could import each layer as its own object and style/visualize them as you like. All of it is free, but it is not ideal if you want to make accurate measurements and it requires that you have an idea of how to work with blender.

Comment: I am not sure how strict the visualization has to be, but it could also be an option to show the 3D elevation and color code how deep the geological layer is compared to the surface (by doing a subtraction of the two layers in the raster calculator).

Comment: Are you looking for elevation profiles? https://www.geodose.com/2018/09/how-to-create-dem-elevation-profile-qgis.html - see also Profile tool plugin and here: https://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Profile_Tool

Comment: @Sam: I will have a look at blender. For the raster calculator. My idea is to visualize more than just two layers. And afterwards I maybe want to extrude between the rasters in order to get a 3D solid.

Comment: @Babel: No it should not be a elevation profile. But for checking resulting rasters I use this tool